# Extend ImageIcon class and keep compatibility

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, scaling, imageicon

I have class Emoticon, it extends ImageIcon.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("", emoticon); // emoticon is from class Emoticon
```

I can't do that because JLabel is looking for ImageIcon, not Emoticon. Can i solve this easily?

I've extended ImageIcon but i'm not sure if i should do that at all.

```
public class Emoticon extends ImageIcon {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Emoticon(String Path, String desc) {
    super(Path, desc);
}

Emoticon(Image image) {
    super(image);
}

public Emoticon getScaled(int width, int height) {
    Image image= this.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    Emoticon ret = new Emoticon(image);
    return ret;

}

}
```

I'm going to expand it little later.

How to make Emoticon compatible with JLabel?

Comment: What do you mean, "[you] can't do that?" Sure you can. If `Emoticon` IS-A `ImageIcon` then it should work fine.

Comment: Which error do you get exactly?

Comment: Yes, *if* it actually makes sense logically for `Emoticon` to be an `ImageIcon`.

Comment: Have you tried casting `emoticon` explicitly as `ImageIcon`? `new JLabel("", (ImageIcon) emoticon, JLabel.CENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

I have made a mistake

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("", emoticon);
```

should be i.e.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("", emoticon, JLabel.CENTER);
```

Thank's Tom G